# Machine check error from DVD

Tags: system-installation

I have a Asrock Z87 Extreme6 board, when I try to boot Ubuntu Saucy with *non UEFI* boot I get a `Machine check error`. If I try with *UEFI*, I get a blank screen.

Any ideas?

Machine configuration:

- Kingston HyperX blu Memory 16GB
- Seagate 1TB SATA600
- Asrock Z87 Extreme6
- Intel Core i5 4570, 3.2GHz
- Asus BW 16D1HT
- *Using onboard GPU*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short: don't use DVI-D, use HDMI >:(

In this post you can see what happened.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107281/instaling-linux-on-a-machine-with-asrock-z87-extreme-6

Long time been since, jsut saw that I left this question open. Closed now!

Answer (score 0):

Could be a BIOS setting error, Ubuntu iso got corrupted, or your machine is not 'Linux ready'. It is also possible that the kernel does not support the machine configurations.

Can you try provide your machine's configuration (such as processor, GPU) so the community could understand what went wrong?

Comment: Added the configuration to the question. Thanks

Comment: Just curious, is your Ubuntu in 64-bit?

Also, possible the kernel does not support your machine yet. Can you try Linux Mint to see if your problem can be solved?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu amd64. I tried with Debian and with Slackware. I think it seems to be something regarding with non-UEFI boot. Maybe with the Motherboard or the Asus BW 16D1HT.
I had no problem installing Windows non-UEFI. I installed Non-UEFI Windows because I thought I could find problems trying to install linux in UEFI. But have problems in both the situations.

After updating the UEFI I was able to load Debian 7.02, but only in UEFI mode not in non-UEFI. Non-UEFI get the same Machine Check error.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you with it. I'm still not very good at UEFI, but I'm just wondering why Linux failed to install in non-EFI mode... It suppose to be able to boot and install. 

But then again, I wish you luck on finding a solution.